# Paddings around the actual vim window in gvim

Tags: vim

In gvim small paddings on the right and bottom sides of a window can appear. Particularly when gvim window is maximized. For example, here is what my bottom-right corner of gvim looks like when I maximize gvim window:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HYiS.jpg

So is there anything I can do with these paddings? For example, move the actual editing area so paddings spread evenly from all four sides of gvim window instead of being only from two sides. Does any section of the manual contains the description of them? There is no real issue here, I'm just curious.

**EDIT:** I'm asking about the Linux version of gvim. I don't know how gvim behaves in similar situation in Windows or on Mac.

Comment: are you seeing this under gvim in Windows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A common fix is to "hack" GTK so that GVim's window background is the same color as the background of your colorscheme. It's obviously less than ideal (you'd have to change it each time you try a new colorscheme) but it works reliably.

Put this code:

```
style "vimfix" {
  bg[NORMAL] = "#202020" # this matches my gvim theme 'Normal' bg color.
}
widget "vim-main-window.*GtkForm" style "vimfix"
```

in this file:

```
~/.gtkrc-2.0
```

Comment: Good that this one did not get migrated, like [the other one](http://superuser.com/a/342227/75721) :)

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your .gvimrc:

```
set ghr=0
```

:help guiheadroom

```
'guiheadroom' 'ghr'     number  (default 50)
                        global
                        {not in Vi} {only for GTK and X11 GUI}
    The number of pixels subtracted from the screen height when fitting
    the GUI window on the screen.  Set this before the GUI is started,
    e.g., in your gvimrc file.  When zero, the whole screen height will
    be used by the window.  When positive, the specified number of pixel
    lines will be left for window decorations and other items on the
    screen.  Set it to a negative value to allow windows taller than the
    screen.
```

I was tipped off to this solution [on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vim#Empty_space_at_the_bottom_of_gVim_windows).

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the `lines` and `columns` options. For example:

```
:set lines=1000
:set columns=1000
```

You can find out about these with `:help lines` and `:help columns`.

Comment: Doesn't help the space. Still there.

Comment: @Connor I'm guessing this question is windows specific: `:set fullscreen` sounds like MacVIM?

Comment: If you maximize the window and increase both 'lines' and 'columns' by 1, then some part of symbols appears out of the range of the screen. Though paddings do disappear. But I was wondering if one can affect the paddings themselves rather than changing them indirectly.

Comment: Just to be clear, vim on my system won't even let me set lines/columns past the visible amount. It just clamps the value to whatever it can display.

Comment: @pb2q Good point. I'm not sure about gVim on Linux, but I believe the same procedure will work for a fullscreen terminal emulator with terminal vim on Linux.

Comment: @Connor: I _believe_ that `:set fullscreen` is a MacVIM addition, but haven't run non-terminal vim on linux

Comment: Indeed `:set fullscreen` doesn't work here in GVim 7.3.35/Ubuntu 11.04 but `:set lines=1000 | set columns=1000` is nice.

Comment: @romainl you can even set multiple options with the same command like `:set lines=1000 columns=1000` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the reason it's there is because windows is forcing it to a size other than it's normal size plus an integer number of character sizes. As far as I know the people who wrote gvim didn't bother to add a centered option.